# Unnesting arrays in Big Query

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Consider the MWE table containing arrays

```
Name  Day.id       Day.Purchase_list
John  [1,2]  [ [10,10,5,5], [20,20,10,10] ]
```

An unnest+cross join is enough to get

```
SELECT name, day.id, day.Purchase list 
FROM table, UNNEST(day) as day 

*Outcome* 

Name     id     Purchase_list 
John     1     [10, 10, 5, 5]    
John     2     [20, 20, 10, 10]
```

However, I would like to keep a single row and expand in columns the information such that the outcome is

```
Name   Purchase_list_day1   Purchase_list_day2
John      [10,10,5,5]         [20,20,10,10]
```

How can I achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: SELECT Name, 
day[OFFSET(0)].purchase_list as purchase_list_day1, day[OFFSET(1)].purchase_list as pruchase_list_day2 does the job but doesn't seem too clean. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think your solution is simple and clean enough! What it is that you think you don’t like in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to reference the arrays

```
select cwe.name,
       day.purchase_list[safe_ordinal(1)] as Purchase_list_day1,
       day.purchase_list[safe_ordinal(2)] as Purchase_list_day2
from cwe;
```